# How to resend an Ajax request, after completing the previous one

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying execuiting a simple Ajax request to a web page (triggered by a onclick event on a button):

```
    // 1. crea un oggetto di tipo XMLHttpRequest
var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
// 2. usa il metodo open per richiedere una risorsa sul sito remoto
myRequest.open('GET', 'http://www.classiperlo.altervista.org/File%20comuni/ora_ajax.php?y=' + Math.random(),true);
// 3. ogni volta che cambia lo stato dell'oggetto esegue una funzione
myRequest.onreadystatechange = function () { 
    // 4. readyState === 4 indica che il server ha risposto
    if (myRequest.readyState === 4) {
        // 5. inserisce il contenuto della risposta in un DIV
        document.getElementById('ajax-content').innerHTML = myRequest.responseText;
    }
};

function sendTheAJAX() {
    myRequest.send();
}
```

I don't understand why, when I click again, I receive always the same information from the server. I mean, my page ora_ajax.php simply displays current time in php and this information is not refreshed when I send a new request.

Where is my error?
Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: Could you add the corresponding `php` code to your question, please?

Comment: Looks like you are using same previous object while sending request again.

Comment: Response is cached, you're appending random value to URL to bypass it but you don't actually ever change it if you're simply calling `sendTheAJAX()` in your click event.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your 'request creation and open' code in another function and call that function when you want to send another request.

```
function sendRequest(){
  var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ...
return myRequest;
}
```

`function sendTheAJAX() {
    sendRequest();
}`

Comment: I tried previous code, by I receive an error
sendRequest.send is not a function

Comment: It is a user made function. In the above code, 'sendTheAJAX' and 'sendRequest' are user made functions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your kind help. Solved simply putting all the code inside the function triggered by onclick event:

```
function sendTheAJAX() {
// 1. crea un oggetto di tipo XMLHttpRequest
var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
// 2. usa il metodo open per richiedere una risorsa sul sito remoto
myRequest.open('GET', 'http://www.classiperlo.altervista.org/File%20comuni/ora_ajax.php?y=' + Math.random(),true);
// 3. ogni volta che cambia lo stato dell'oggetto esegue una funzione
myRequest.onreadystatechange = function () { 
    // 4. readyState === 4 indica che il server ha risposto
    if (myRequest.readyState === 4) {
        // 5. inserisce il contenuto della risposta in un DIV
        document.getElementById('ajax-content').innerHTML = myRequest.responseText;
    }
};

    myRequest.send();
}
```

In this way a new object myRequest is created at every click on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Put all of the XHR code inside `sendTheAJAX` above `.send()`, then call the entire thing, otherwise the `Math.random()` never changes.

After reading your comment, you can just remove that part. Seems you don't need it.

Note that if you were to use it `Math.random()` returns a number between 0 and 0.99999999, never 1.

```
function sendTheAJAX(successFunc, context){
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest, c = context || this;
  xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.classiperlo.altervista.org/File%20comuni/ora_ajax.php');
  if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200){
    successFunc.call(c, xhr.responseText);
  }
  xhr.send();
  return xhr;
}
function yup(){
  sendTheAJAX(function(respTxt){
    document.getElementById('ajax-content').innerHTML = respTxt;
  });
}
yup(); // remove if you don't want call here
document.body.onclick = yup;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It looks like your solution is quite similar to mine or am I wrong? I don't understand your explanation about Math,random. For me it doesn't matter what Math.random actually returns. It is just a trick to avoid caching. Is there any error?

Comment: Your Server will execute the request each time you make one, actually, so I don't know about this caching thing you speak of.